# How do i start installing Xbuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu

Ive downloaded the .iso which is too large for a CD, so Im unclear what Im meant to do with it ( cannot find any instructions on the Xbuntu website) , do I just copy the iso to a usb stick ?

I don't currently have a linux machine but I do have a Windows and Apple mac machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a DVD or a USB ( at least 1GB in size)
You can use the following tool in Windows to copy your ISO to a USB.

[LinuxLiveUSB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

I dont have a mac but a simple Google found this on the Ubuntu website

[Create Ubuntu USB from Mac OSX](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

Comment: thx I burned to USB using his http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ and have now installed Xubuntu ok, it was just confusing as there was no installtion instructions